# Cant change the BackColor of an PictureBox Array

Tags: c#, split, backcolor

I am trying to create a `.txt` File which I can open with my program and save all the Numbers in two different arrays by splitting them.
But for some reason the top part never changes the [`BackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is the Code:

```
        PictureBox[,] Field = new PictureBox[4, 4];
        int[,] Block_Property = new int[4, 4];

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                Field[x, y] = new PictureBox();
                Field[x, y].Size = new Size(64, 64);
                Field[x, y].Location = new Point(x * 64, y * 64);
                this.Controls.Add(Field[x, y]);
            }
        }

        string Text;
        int Zahler=0;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Level/1-1.txt"))
        {
            Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        string[] Feld = Text.Split(';');
        for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                if(Feld[Zahler] == "1")
                {
                    Field[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
                Zahler++;
                if (Feld[Zahler] == "1")
                {
                    Block_Property[x, y] = 1;
                }
                Zahler++;
            }
        }
```

This is how my `.txt` File looks:

```
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;     
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;    
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;      
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;
```

Here is how it looks after I start the program:

[image: How it looks after I start the program]

Answer (score 0):

X should be Y

```
for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
                {
                    if (Feld[Zahler] == "1")
                    {
                        Field[y, x].BackColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    Zahler++;
                    if (Feld[Zahler] == "1")
                    {
                        Block_Property[y, x] = 1;
                    }
                    Zahler++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Now the 3 White Pictureboxes are one the Left side instead of the top

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead of hard coding the x and y of the array, and y and x need to be switch

```
        for (int y = 0; y < Field.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Field.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
               if(Feld[Zahler] == "1")
               {
                  Field[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
               }

               Zahler++;

                if (Feld[Zahler] == "1")
                {
                  Block_Property[x, y] = 1;
                }

                 Zahler++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Now the 3 White Pictureboxes are one the Left side instead of the top